# Importing csv file into mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to import data into mysql through a csv file using PHP, while doing so i get the following error:

**upload file name: test.csv You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'name,Country,Currency) values('Company name','Country','Currency')' at line 1**

So please help me out in solving the above error
Thanks in advance

This is the code which i am using

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = '';

$database = 'automation';
$table = 'company';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");


    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
         $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
         echo 'upload file name: '.$fname.' ';
         $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

         if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) == "csv")
         {

             $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
             $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

             while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
             {
                $sql = "INSERT into company(Company name,Country,Currency) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')";
                mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
             }

             fclose($handle);
             echo "Successfully Imported";

         }
         else
         {
             echo "Invalid File";
         }   
    }

    ?>
    <h1>Import CSV file</h1>
    <form action='<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Import File : <input type='file' name='sel_file' size='100'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
    </form>
```

Comment: Problem is with space in column name `Company name` you need to keep inside into backtick

Comment: This part `INSERT into company(Company name,Country,Currency)` do you want it like `....(Company, name....` OR  `....(\`Company name\`....`

Comment: The field name specified in the table in "Company name" and it is one field

Comment: as @Saty said make it like `....(\`Company name\`....`

Comment: @SagarGuhe how do you make backticks in inline code block? tried escaping them with backslash and it didn't work for me...

Comment: Thanks a lot to you both, the backtick worked.  :)

Comment: @pamblam use the one below the tild button (~) as the backtick

Comment: hahahaha @Pamblam I just did the same as you thought.. I just escaped it with `\\` ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the column `company name` is two words you have to wrap it in backticks.

If there are quotes in the data (or god forbid, some kind of SQL injection) you're basically doomed.

`mysql_*` is deprecated and not safe to use. You should look into PDO or MySQLi prepared statements.

And, if this is a one-time upload consider using phpMyAdmin to import your CSV.